# WebView unable to save cookie on Android 2.3.x

Tags: android, android-webview

So I've been trying to get a `WebView` to work properly to authenticate a user session that is used in app. It works on all 4.0+ devices but when I try to use the same process on a 2.3.6 and 2.3.7 devices it throws this exception in the log:

```
com.myapp.WebActivity E/webkit﹕ parse cookie failed for: request_uri=xxxxxxxx; path=/; expires=Mon, 16-Jun-2014 00:00:00; domain=;
```

It doesn't crash the app but will not save this one cookie needed to properly authenticate the users session. I've looked into the Android Source code and it appears that when trying to save this specific cookie there is a `RunTimeException` that is happening. [Here is the Android Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/webkit/CookieManager.java#330) where the exception is thrown and caught. I'm not 100% sure where to look next since the cookies are saved properly on 4.0+ and it seems like a AOSP bug. Also, after the WebView loads the `CookieManager` doesn't have the cookie that it threw the exception on but has others.

So my real question is: Is there anyway to manually get a cookie returned from a WebView page load or can I get the cookie to be saved by the Android 2.3 WebView automatically somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use to check and save a cookie that is picked up by a subsequent WebView. It works on Android 2.2 for sure, as well as Android 4.X.

Checking:

```
// see if the cookie is already set up
boolean cookieAlreadySetUp = false;
String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(urlHost);
if ( cookie != null && cookie.length() > 0 ) {
    String[] cookies = cookie.split(";");

    for ( int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++ ) {
        String oneCookie = cookies[i];
        if ( oneCookie.trim().equals(SharedData.COOKIE_STRING) ) {
            cookieAlreadySetUp = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Saving:

```
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setCookie(urlHost, myCookieString);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

// give time for the cookie to become known since the save process is asynchronous to this thread
SystemClock.sleep(100);
```

Be aware of the asynchronous nature of the cookie manager, both for adding or removing a cookie, as well as testing its existence.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This didn't really solve the problem because the cookie I need was never put in the CookieManager; it seemed to get that RunTimeException I mentioned above before it was saved to the CookieManager. So the CookieManager would only have 2 of the 3 cookies I needed.

Comment: @Floofer - Try stopping in the debugger to see what might be causing the exception. Maybe there is a strange character in your cookie, like '=' or something that breaks the parse. Maybe the cookie has an illegal date. Just making guesses...